# Ajax form serialize doesnt bind when using multiple parameters in MVC Controller

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model

I have a view with multiple inputs for my Model (Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.attribute) etc. And my ajax method is:

```
function callMethod() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: $('#Form').serialize() ,
        url: '@Url.Action("formMethod", "Test")',
    }).done(function (newTable) {
        $('#RefundTableDiv').html(newTable);
    });
};
```

and this works perfectly, the model comes perfectly to formMethod, but when i change formMethod and add another parameter for example 'int test' it doesnt work anymore.

My method looks like:

```
function callMethod() {
 var number = 2;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {"model": $('#Form').serialize(),
               "test": number}, 
        url: '@Url.Action("formMethod", "Test")',
    }).done(function (newTable) {
        $('#RefundTableDiv').html(newTable);
    });
};
```

the "test": number does come correctly to the method in the controller but the model suddenly is null now?

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: the model is null because you're sending JSON with a url-encoded string within it. You can't mix the formats like that. Your controller just thinks "model" is a random string value. Either submit everything as JSON, or everything as regular query parameters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `.serialize()` serializes your model as a query string (e.g. `someProperty=someValue&anotherProperty=anotherValue&...`). To add additional name/value pairs, you can append then manually, for example

```
var data = $('#Form').serialize() + '&test=' + number;
$.ajax({
    ....
    data: data;
```

or use the [param()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) method (useful if you have multiple items and/or arrays to add)

```
 var data = $("#Form").serialize() + '&' + $.param({ test: number }, true);
 $.ajax({
    ....
    data: data;
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do it like this:

```
function callMethod() {
    var number = 2;
    var sd = $('#Form').serializeArray();
    sd.push({ name:"test", value:number });

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: sd,
        url: '@Url.Action("formMethod", "Test")',
    }).done(function (newTable) {
        $('#RefundTableDiv').html(newTable);
    });
};
```