# (MVC 5) Action model parameter always null by passing array via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an action like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,Name,Age")] Person p, IEnumerable<Guid> areas)
{
        ...
}
```

From my view I'm doing an ajax:

```
$("#formPerson").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var checkedAreas = [];
        $(".bereich:checked").each(function () {
            checkedAreas.push($(this).val());
        });

        var payload = {
            p : $(this).serialize(),
            areas : checkedAreas 
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("Create", "Home"))",
            type: "post",
            data: payload
        })
})
```

My problem is, that the action attribute `Person p` is always null. Why?

When putting `data: $(this).serialize()` in my ajax request it works fine, but putting an array `data: payload` it is going to be null. Any ideas?

Comment: You cannot use `$(this).serialize()` (which creates the name/value pairs in a query string format) inside an object.

Comment: You can use `$(this).serialize()` in combination with `$.param()` as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46525744/ajax-form-serialize-doesnt-bind-when-using-multiple-parameters-in-mvc-controller/46534357#46534357)

Comment: @StephenMuecke thank you! It's working now.